# Set SelectedItem on ListBox bound to DataTable

Tags: vb.net, winforms, .net-4.0, datatable, listbox

So this seems like it should be easy, but I can't quite figure out the syntax needed here as I'm more used to WPF / c#.  Basically I have a ListBox bound to a DataTable and I want to select an item based on an ID value.  Something like this.

```
lstUsers.DataSource = dtUsers
lstUsers.DisplayMember = "UserName"
lstUsers.SelectedItem = dtUsers.Select(String.Format("ID = {0}", myID))(0)
```

I can see `dtUsers.Select(String.Format("ID = {0}", myID))(0)` is returning the correct DataRow in the debugger, but setting the SelectedItem does nothing.  I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here, but everything I have tried has had no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution

```
lstUsers.DataSource = dtUsers
lstUsers.DisplayMember = "UserName"
lstUsers.ValueMember = "ID"
lstUsers.SelectedValue = dtUsers.Select(String.Format("ID = {0}", myID))(0)("ID")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `LINQ-To-DataSet`:

```
var rows = dtUsers.AsEnumerable()
                   .Select((row,index) => new{ row,index })
                   .Where(x => x.row.Field<int>("ID")==myID);
if(rows.Any())
    lstUsers.SelectedIndex = rows.First().index;
```

in VB.NET:

```
Dim rows = dtUsers.AsEnumerable().
    Select(Function(r, i) New With {.row = r, .index = i}).
    Where(Function(x) x.row.Field(Of Int32)("ID") = myID)
If rows.Any Then
    lstUsers.SelectedIndex = rows.First().index
End If
```

Note that you need to add `Imports System.Linq` (`using System.Linq;` in C#)

Comment: This is in VB not c#, also even though it is a .NET 4.0 project, it was recently converted and I would rather accomplish this without LINQ so I don't have to add more DLL references to the project.

Comment: @KDiTraglia: I have overlooked the VB.NET tag, sorry. [LINQ's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.aspx) `System.Core.dll` is normally added automatically in 4.0.

Comment: It is for new projects, but this was converted from an old vb6 app (And I'd rather not add DLL references for such a trivial change).  I found a solution *see below* that does this pretty easily without LINQ.  Thanks for the answer though.

Answer (score 1):

`SelectedItem` you used in the question is actually much more reliable solution than offered answers with `SelectedIndex` or `SelectedValue`.

- `SelectedIndex` can easily run out of bounds and then throw an exception.
- `SelectedValue` can find wrong value if two items lead to same `ToString()`
- `SelectedItem` matches directly ***the object*** behind the list item. If there is no match, the listbox is left without selected item. The only mistake you made in example in your question was that you tried to assign `String` to `SelectedItem`, but originally you did not populate `SelectedItem` with Strings. What was type of every item in your `DataSource`? Using that one will work.

**Example:** if you add items `i1`, `i2`, `i3` of type *myClass* into *ListBox.Items*, they will display their values `i1.ToString()`, `i2.ToString()`, `i3.ToString()` in the *ListBox* but in *ListBox.Items* collection they will remain `i1`, `i2`, `i3`. Then you can use `ListBox.SelectedItem = i2` and item `i2` will get selected. But if you try `ListBox.SelectedItem = i2.ToString()`, **it will NOT work**, because there is **no match**. This is what you attempted in example in your question and why it did not work.

If you work with objects in your list, stick with `SelectedItem` in your work, do not go with `SelectedIndex` or `SelectedValue` which have their disadvantages.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code instead.

```
for (var i = 0; i < lstUsers.Items.Count; i++)
    if ((listBox1.Items[i] as YourClass).ID == myID)
      listBox1.SelectedIndex = i;
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, `YourClass` would be a DataRow in this case and it is giving me an invalid cast.  Also this is in VB not c#.

Comment: In the case of using a DataTable, the item types that are bound to the ListBox will each be a `DataRowView`. Thus, to get the selected item:
`Dim mySelected As DataRow = CType(ListBox1.SelectedItem, DataRowView).Row`